# Why I can't see the performance difference between Spring Boot and Vert.x

Tags: spring, spring-boot, vert.x

One advantage of Vert.X is it's performance, but I can't see any difference from my testing, any one know why? The test is simply printing hello.

I have also perform a testing for requesting Google(async request in Vert.x) then print response. It also shows 2 framework have same performance.

Vert.x Code:

```
public class MainVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {
  static String HELLO = "hello";
  @Override
  public void start(Promise<Void> startPromise) throws Exception {
    vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(req -> {
      req.response()
        .putHeader("content-type", "text/plain")
        .end(HELLO );
    }).listen(8888, http -> {
      if (http.succeeded()) {
        startPromise.complete();
        System.out.println("HTTP server started on port 8888");
      } else {
        startPromise.fail(http.cause());
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Spring code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class DemoApplication {

    static String HELLO = "hello";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String hei(){
        return HELLO;
    }
}
```

Apache Benchmark(calling from another machine):

```
ab -n 50000 -c 10 http://192.168.1.115:8888/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply put, you don't see performance benefits because you're testing the wrong things.

Vert.x, and asynchronous frameworks in general, are great for IO bound operations. And it so happens that most read world applications are IO bound (waiting for DB, disk, other services, etc).

Your application doesn't perform any significant IO, though. So, that's one reason you don't see a difference.

Another reason is the concurrency level you are using. Spring applications are bound by their thread pool size, but my guess is it's bigger than 10 threads, so you aren't really stressing your application.

The third reason is that you are most likely running this test on the same machine than your server is running. This is flawed, because your Vert.x application will compete for resources with `ab`.

Comment: Hi Alexey, thanks for answering. 1: I know Vert.x is good for async IO operation, so I have perform a test with async http request, but which show no difference from the result. 2: I am referring data from "Web Framework Benchmarks" and so many blog, they all claim even print a plain text Vert.x is way better than spring. 3: I do test from another machine in local network

Comment: Actually I try 1000 concurrent user, but same result. I guess 1000 is still too low? For most application, 1000 is pretty enough I think.

Comment: @Rockman12352 Looking at the numbers, Spring is able to handle 200K requests per second in the Plaintext:
https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=data-r20&hw=ph&test=plaintext

So you'll have a hard time stressing your application that much, I think.

Comment: yup, from this benchmark Vert.x is 10x better than Spring, but from my own testing, they are almost identical. So I wonder what happened.

Comment: As I said above, you need between 30K to 200K concurrent users to stress Spring application with plaintext test. You can try `-c 30000` from a single machine, but it would be better if your run this from multiple machines.

Comment: ab is not able to set concurrent user to 30K, so I try wrk. Vert.x shows its advantage this time, around 10% better than Spring and cost less memory.